# Linux list open ports to the outside

Tags: linux, security, linux-networking

I can't find how to list or 'read the list' of ports open on Linux.
I have a Debian based server. I found a slew of commands to list open ports, but I can't find any that lists just of open ports that can be accessed from the outside.
I know 3309 is open, but I've configured mySQL to only reply to local host, but the port is still listed as open. Again, I'm only interested in ports open to the outside world.

If there is no such command, maybe there is a grep to filter out the internal only ports?

Comment: Please readup on Linux networking. To show listening ports you could start with "netstat -tulpen" or "lsof -i". Linux knows also the concept of firewalls to restrict access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not be finding an easy answer to this, because it's a more complex question than you might realize. There's at least 3 possible points of interest to look at:

1. The ports being listened for on the server. `netstat -an | grep LISTEN` will give you a general idea.  Look for source addresses of 0.0.0.0 or specific "outside" interfaces (don't forget IPv6 addresses if applicable).
2. Server firewall (commonly iptables). `iptables -l` will give some idea of what traffic is being allowed.  But also, it should show you any NATs/port redirects being done at the server level.  For example, your port 3309 might be redirected to 127.0.0.1:3309.  So even though your mysql might only be listening on localhost, it WOULD be technically accessible from the "outside" world.
3. Your edge firewall.  This is your internet router/gateway. Easiest thing to do here is to go to a server in the "outside world" (whether that's the open internet, somewhere else on your network, etc. - that wasn't clearly defined in the question), and run `nmap <your-external-ip>` and see what it reports as open.  The downside of doing this is if you don't have a dedicated IP for your server, you're probably going to see a lot of stuff that doesn't apply to your specific server.

Those 3 things will answer most of your questions, but I'm sure others will have more ideas/suggestions.

Comment: didn't know internal nat-ing is possible. Is there a command that lists all internal nats/port redirects and ONLY those? My iptables also lists all fail2ban chains and it's rather laborious to look trough..

Comment: So, Would `netstat -ntlp | grep -vEe "\s+127[.]|::1` AND `iptables -t nat -L -n -v` be enough to check ALL the ports to the outside world? 
Of course, your 3rd points is valid, but my main concern is the local machine.

Comment: You would probably want to also check your input chains to see what's allowed or not (without considering nat)

Answer (score 7):

Hi and welcome to ServerFault.

How about this?

```
ss -tulpen | grep -vEe "\s+127[.]|::1"
```

This drops 127.0.0.0/8 and ::1 addresses from the output.

While this does list all TCP and UDP ports listening on addresses reachable on this box, it doesn't tell you if they are *actually* reachable. A firewall (IPTables/Netfilter, external device) or security policy (SELinux, SystemD, tcpwrappers) might still block access.

**edit**
If you want to know that ports *are indeed* accessible from the outside world, place a host in said "outside world" (e.g. the Internet) and run a port scanner (like nmap) on that host targeting your server.

Sample for nmap:

```
sudo nmap -sS -p1-65535 <your_server's_ip>
```

Comment: Does this 
`netstat -ntlp | grep -vEe "\s+127[.]|::1`
return the same list, just a bit nicer? I assume 0.0.0.0 and :::* mean 'internet'?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 and ::: mean "listen on any local address" (i.e. wildcard) for IPv4 and IPv6 respectively.  Subtle difference between that and 'internet'

Answer (score 0):

You can use netstat command.
the switches that need to be used with netstat command to show you the program name, port number, protocol, which the daemon is listening on the server is as below.

```
netstat -ntlp
```